# Convert hook_menu in drupal 8

Tags: 8, hooks

I have a hook_menu as follows :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function conditional_fields_menu() {
  $items = array();

  foreach (node_get_types() as $type) {
    $content_type = content_types($type->type);

    $items['admin/content/node-type/' . $content_type['url_str'] . '/conditional'] = array(
      'title' => 'Conditional fields',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('_conditional_fields_admin', $content_type['type']),
      'access arguments' => array('administer conditional fields'),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'weight' => 5
      );
  }

  return $items;
}
```

How can i convert this to **`conditional_fields.routing.yml`** in d8 ?

what i tried :

## Drupal 8 conditional_fields.routing.yml snippet

```
conditional_fields.admin:
  path: 'admin/content/node-type/{this is unknown}/conditional'
  defaults:
    _form: '_conditional_fields_admin'
    _title: 'Conditional fields'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer conditional fields'
```

Comment: What do you mean with `this is unknown`? What you should enter there? Have a look at [node.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.routing.yml/8) You can enter a variable that will be read and can be used later on in the .yml file.

Answer (score 3):

The routing system uses pattern matching. You can define a parameter in the path that will be used as a variable.

If we look at this snippet of [node.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.routing.yml/8):

```
node.add:
  path: '/node/add/{node_type}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::add'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::addPageTitle'
  requirements:
    _node_add_access: 'node:{node_type}'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node_type:
        with_config_overrides: TRUE
```

You can see the `{node_type}` in the path. This variable will contain the node type as specified in the path. You can use that as part of the requirement as you can see above, and it will also be available to your functions. [`\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::add`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Controller%21NodeController.php/function/NodeController%3A%3Aadd/8.1.x) receives the `node_type` variable as well:

```
public function add(NodeTypeInterface $node_type) {
  $node = $this->entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
    'type' => $node_type->id(),
  ));

  $form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($node);

  return $form;
}
```

Read [Parameters in routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186285) for more information.

And for forms:

```
example.user_form
  path: 'example/form/{user}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\example\Form\ExampleForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

You can use the `buildForm` function and place the additional parameters after `$form` and `$form_state`.

```
namespace Drupal\example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

class BasicForm extends FormBase {

 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, AccountInterface $user = NULL) {
    // Do something with $user in the form
  }
}
```

Comment: But node module for d8 is not available , so how can i implement this ?

Comment: How do you mean? This is example of how the routing is done in the node module. Node module ships with D8 core so it is available.

Comment: ok i got it from drupal/core/modules/node , thanks

Comment: can you pls give a full replacement with respect to my code , if possible

Comment: Everything you need to know is in my examples and the linked resources. Please read the 'parameters in routes' article I linked to. Understand it and then look at the code again.