# How do I use variables in links.task.yml?

Tags: 8, routes

I have a local **`links.task.yml`** file to display the tab for the node data , But it seems to have a problem passing argument to the path . As you can see I am extending the node's basic fetaures like **edit,delete.revision** with an additional function using tab.  I have **`module_name.links.task.yml`**

```
entity.node.check_backend:
  route_name: module_name.my_route
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: My title
```

And I have the route in **`module_name.routing.yml`**  as follows:

```
module_name.my_route:
  path: '/node/{arg1}/function_name'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module_name\Controller\ControllerName::function_name'
    _title: 'My title'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access admin tab'
```

But it throws me errors like:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException:
> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("arg1") to generate a URL for
> route "module_name.my_route".

How can I pass variables in links.task.yml file ?

Comment: I already attempted to answered this to you in [Convert hook_menu in drupal 8](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198768/convert-hook-menu-in-drupal-8). Also have a look at the linked resource (halfway in the asnwer): [Parameters in Routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186285) and the sub-pages.

Comment: I think you mistaken the question , its to use parameters in **links.yml** not in **routing.yml**

Comment: Links are only references to routes. The error comes from your routing.

Comment: I guess, because you are working with nodes, your variable should be called `{node}` so the existing node routing can work with it. Can you try that in your routing file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `{arg1}` in your route and your `links.task.yml` file is registering that as an item that should use base route `entity.node.canonical`. As you can read in this [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2306387), the value for `entity.node.canonical` will become `node/[nid]`.

In your situation, you are providing a variable `arg1`, when the node routing system is expecting a `node` variable.

Just make sure that all sub-pages share the same base path as their parents.

Answer (score 19):

In your module_name.links.task.yml file you can add a route_parameters: array that lists the parameters you want to pass, in your case it would end up:

```
entity.node.check_backend:
  route_name: module_name.my_route
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: My title
  route_parameters:
    arg1:  'value_for_arg1'
```

You can find this by looking at the code in \Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager which parses this file.

Comment: How would you get the node id to pass it as argument?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a class to generate dynamic tabs, and take example on the core tracker module which supports this.

Let's take a look in the `tracker.links.task.yml` file :

```
tracker.users_recent_tab:
route_name: tracker.users_recent_content
title: 'My recent content'
base_route: tracker.page
class: '\Drupal\tracker\Plugin\Menu\UserTrackerTab'
```

And then the `\Drupal\tracker\Plugin\Menu\UserTrackerTab` class :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\tracker\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskDefault;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

/**
 * Provides route parameters needed to link to the current user tracker tab.
 */
class UserTrackerTab extends LocalTaskDefault {

  /**
   * Current user object.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * Gets the current active user.
   *
   * @todo: https://www.drupal.org/node/2105123 put this method in
   *   \Drupal\Core\Plugin\PluginBase instead.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected function currentUser() {
    if (!$this->currentUser) {
      $this->currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
    }
    return $this->currentUser;
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getRouteParameters(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return ['user' => $this->currentUser()->Id()];
  }

}
```

So you should create your own class like this one and implement the `getRouteParameters` method to return the array with the right parameters to be used. Simple like that :)

Reference to a well written article about this : https://medium.com/@joshirohit100/dynamic-tabs-in-drupal-8-8a76386e212c

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "route_parameters" key in module_name.links.task.yml and pass the variables with value.
Here is the working code :
In  `module_name.routing.yml`  file

```
sg_custom.loading_form:
  path: '/form/loading_form/{page}'
  defaults: 
    _form: '\Drupal\sg_custom\Form\LoadingForm'
    _title: 'Loading Form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

And in  `module_name.links.task.yml`  file

```
sg_custom.tab_1:
  route_name: sg_custom.loading_form
  title: Loading Start
  base_route: sg_custom.loading_form
  route_parameters: 
    page: start_loading

sg_custom.tab_2:
  route_name: sg_custom.loading_form
  title: Loading End
  base_route: sg_custom.loading_form
  route_parameters: 
    page: end_loading
```